# Possible to have kafka producer sending topic to cloud server instead of localhost:9092

Tags: apache-kafka

In other words: Kafka consumer on cloud and Kafka producer on the client.

I am in need to write a Kafka consumer, where 3rd party application would send msgs.
But they do not have any server exposed to the public domain.
I am having a server, so, I would like to know, if I can write my Consumer on localhost of the server and Kafka producer can use the IP of my server.
Is this ok? or I am wrong in my approach?

$ bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --topic quickstart-events --bootstrap-server localhost:9092

Can this localhost:9092 be Another IP:9092?

Comment: Yes, provided that IP: Port is open for the machine that you are using the Kafka console producer. – Ideally, the third party should be allowed to send messages to Kafka through a secure channel. If exposing Kafka port is not possible, you could deploy your own application that received the message over the REST and that application can reroute the message to Kafka. You could use Kafka client APIs for that instead of using console producer.

Comment: Thank you, Sanju Thomas, I would check this out!